# How to get 'Bills and Adjustment' grid fields in an endpoint extension

Tags: acumatica

I'm working with a client on obtaining Bills and Adjustments values through the Contract based web services.  I understand that certain fields aren't available in the Default Endpoint, and have to be obtained through an extension.

I'm trying to add fields from the Bills and Adjustments' Applications tab, but I'm running into a warning that I don't understand.   If I extend the Default endpoint for 'Bills' (call it 'BillExt'), and I try to add the Reference Number field from the 'Applications' tab/grid (or any other field from that grid) - I get the following warning (see screenshot below)...

Can someone explain what the issue is, and how I go about adding these fields from the 'Applictaions' tab/grid?  I've added fields from the 'Approval Details' grid without this warning without a problem.  Is this a warning I can disregard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a field from another table/view that can return multiple rows for a single Bill.
The correct way to do this is by adding a separate collection on the object and map the view on that collection. e.g: Applications or Details collections here.
[image]

That collection will have the information for all records related to the header once you retrieve them using the `?$expand=Details` on the query string request.

Comment: To add to @diegoapereza's answer -- you should be able use the existing "applications" collection which already exists - and then add the desired fields to it.   It's all a matter of finding the correct hierarchy in the entities.

Comment: Thanks, both Diego and Diane!!  ;D